# Вызов события контроллера с помощью js

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Как вызвать метод контроллера `Assortiment` с помощью скрипта и передать в него значение Category. При нажатии на кнопку вылезает ошибка

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
sort_submit @ Assortiment?Category=all:43
onclick @ Assortiment?Category=all:40
```

cshtml:

```
<input id="Category" onfocus="if (this.value == '@ViewBag.Category') {this.value = ''; this.style.color = '#000';}"
    onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '@ViewBag.Category'; this.style.color = '#777';}"
    type="text" value=@ViewBag.Category />
<input onclick="sort_submit(Category)" type="button" value="Sort" />
<script>
    function sort_submit(Category) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Admin/Assortiment',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { Category: Category },
            success: null
        })
    }
</script>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Assortiment(String Category)
{
    if (Category == "all" || Category == null)
    {
        Item[] items = DBProvider.getAllItems();
        ViewBag.items = items;
        ViewBag.Category = "Category";
        return View();
    }
    else
    {
        Item[] items = DBProvider.getItemsByCategory(Category);
        ViewBag.items = items;
        ViewBag.Category = Category;
        return View();
    }
}
```

upd:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
e @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5
Vb @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5
Vb @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5
Vb @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5
m.param @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5
m.extend.ajax @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5
sort_submit @ Assortiment?Category=all:44
onclick @ Assortiment?Category=all:41
```

44 строка : `$.ajax({`

Comment: добавьте `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`в секцию `head` и обработчик `success` в `$.ajax`

Comment: @Igor теперь такая ошибка Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation, как правильно тип задать?

Comment: что такое `Category` в `onclick="sort_submit(Category)"`?

Comment: Поменяйте `data: { String: Category },` на `data: { Category: Category },`

Comment: @Igor та же самая ошибка

Comment: Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос, показав Ваш код на данный момент, укажите полное сообщение об ошибке и на какой строке ошибка происходит.

Comment: @Igor, отредактировал

Comment: Спасибо. Повторю свой вопрос: что такое `Category` в `onclick="sort_submit(Category)"`?

Comment: @Igor, значение `<input id="Category" onfocus="if (this.value == '@ViewBag.Category') {this.value = ''; this.style.color = '#000';}"
                onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '@ViewBag.Category'; this.style.color = '#777';}"
                type="text" value=@ViewBag.Category />`, точнее то, что там написано.

Comment: @Igor, или в скрипте должен быть `text` вместо `Category`

Comment: В вызове `onclick="sort_submit(Category)"` Вы используете глобальную переменную `Category`, которая, я подозреваю, нигде не определена. Временно замените ее на: `onclick="sort_submit('all')"`

Comment: или на `onclick="sort_submit($('#Category').val())"`

Comment: @Igor, ничего не происходит, в обоих случаях

Comment: Естественно, ничего не происходит. Вы же сами написали, что если все хорошо, то ничего делать не надо: `success: null`.

Comment: @Igor тогда что должно быть в `success`, чтобы выполнился метод контроллера с аргументами?

Comment: почитайте, пожалуйста, http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если Category переменная то:

```
<input onclick="sort_submit('@Category')" type="button" value="Sort" />
```